# Using OOP to create multiple sprite objects in Corona LUA

Tags: oop, lua, coronasdk

Since there is very little code I decided to post it all below.

The core of the OOP code I'm trying to create starts at the initialization of `Balloon`

I'm setting the balloon (imageRect) as a sprite property for each Balloon instance.

Then I have a `tapListener` to tell the balloon instance to move when tapped.

However, when I tap on any of the 3 balloons created, only one of the balloons move.

I'm guessing this has something to do with a global reference to a self object, or the scope being changed in `tapListener` function.

Any ideas?

You can just run the code below it's all there!

```
local background = display.newImageRect( "background.png", 460, 570 )
background.x = display.contentCenterX
background.y = display.contentCenterY

local platform = display.newImageRect( "platform.png", 300, 50 )
platform.x = display.contentCenterX
platform.y = display.contentHeight-25

local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

physics.addBody( platform, "static" )

Balloon = {xloc = display.contentCenterX, yloc = display.contentCenterY}
function Balloon:new (o)
    o = o or {}  
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    self.sprite = display.newImageRect("balloon.png", 112, 112)
    self.sprite.x = o.xloc
    self.sprite.y = o.yloc
    physics.addBody(self.sprite, "dynamic", {radius=50, bounce=0.4})
    return o
end

function Balloon:push()
    self.sprite:applyLinearImpulse(0.2, -0.75, self.sprite.x-10, self.sprite.y)
end

function Balloon:tapListener()
    self.sprite:addEventListener("tap", function() self:push() end)
end

balloons = {}

for i=1,3,1 do
    balloons[i] = Balloon:new{xloc=display.contentWidth-(120*i)+60}
    balloons[i]:tapListener()
end
```

Comment: Inside `Balloon:new` you should work with `o.sprite` instead of `self.sprite`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it correct to say, using `self` in the constructor is equivalent to a static class variables?

Comment: Also, do you know if it is necessary for me to have that nested function in `tapListener` just to pass `self:push` as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, nested function is necessary (otherwise how to pass `self` as argument?)